# Detect the image being uploaded in Android application

Tags: android

I was doing some R&D on how to check in android programming whether the image that the user is about to upload is of a person only.

Let me illustrate this, while selecting the image from phone, I want to apply the code that user should only select the image of a person.

I am very new to Android programming and not aware of much, any details on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No you cannot do this, perhaps you can force user to select images from a particular folder.

Comment: You mean, that when user wants to select picture, all available pictures would be of people faces pretty much? If so you'd probably would need to create your own image picker I think. Get all pictures in user's phone, apply your algorithm to detect people (there are libraries for that) and show only pictures that pass the criteria.

Comment: @Edgar.A yes you are right and pretty much closer to my actual requirements. Please specify the name of the libraries.

Comment: There are multiple ones, quick google search gave me this - https://github.com/kairosinc/Kairos-SDK-Android